# PHP submit automatically to one page and manually to another

Tags: php, html, forms

Rajesh I succeeded to submit the page using javascript onclick event like you told me but now for some reason the variables don’t get submitted to the javascript redirect page.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help.
Here is my new code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!--For dropdown auto submit-->
<script>function onSelectChange(){
 document.getElementById("myselect").submit();
}</script>
<!--For final page submit-->
<script>
function submit() {
    window.location = "action_page.php";
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">

<select name="s1" style="width: 70px;" id="mySelect" onchange="this.form.submit()" </select>
              <optgroup label="170011 Non-Isolated RS-422">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="170011-3" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170011-3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0011-3v3</option>
              <option value="170011-5" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170011-5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0011-5v0</option>
              <optgroup label="170013 Isolated LVTTL Input">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="170013-3" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170013-3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0013-3v3</option>
              <option value="170013-5" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170013-5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0013-5v0</option>
              <optgroup label="170015 Isolated LVDS Input">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="170015-3" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170015-3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0015-3v3</option>
              <option value="170015-5" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170015-5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0015-5v0</option>
              <optgroup label="170016 Isolated RS-422 Input">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="170016-3" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170016-3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0016-3v3</option>
              <option value="170016-5" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170016-5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0016-5v0</option>
              <optgroup label="170017 Non-Isolated LVTTL Input">
              <option value="">Select...</option>
              <option value="170017-3" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170017-3') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0017-3v3</option>
              <option value="170017-5" <?php if ($_POST['s1'] == '170017-5') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0017-5v0</option>
    </select></form>

<!--<input type="submit" id="form_page" value="Submit">-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit Final" onclick="submit()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a comment, you have bad HTML there. You have two closing  `</body>` tags and you have two `<form>` tags which appear to be self-closing (they end with `/>`). But forms can't be self-closing.

Comment: There are a few things I notice here, but maybe not all of what's causing difficulties. First, I see `</selec>>` instead of `</select>`. Then, I notice the select element is not inside a `<form>` so its `this.form.submit()` does not reference a form.

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). You should give the different id to form tag and button tag.

You've gave same id in form tag and button tag. You've take two form tags and you've taken Submit button instead simple button. So html document only consider first form tag so when you click on button you will simply redirect to **test.php**

Now for redirect to another url using button you can use javascript onclick event like:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="yourfunction">
```

and in function redirect using javascript like:

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rajesh. Now it works but the variables don't get submited using javascript redirect.